# Как организовать запуск функции раз в 5 минут при бесконечном цикле?

Tags: c, таймер

Есть программа, написанная на СИ, в которой реализован бесконечный цикл: программа ждет ввода строки от пользователя и дает определенный ответ. В программе реализована функция, которая обновляет в памяти некие данные из файла. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, способ, чтобы раз в 5 минут программа запускала эту функцию для обновления.
Пример программы:

```
void update() {
 берем данные из файла и грузим в память
}

void main() {
 while(true) {
  получаем от пользователя данные, если он что-то ввел
  отдаем ответ, на основе данных из памяти
  каждые 5 минут запускаем функцию update()
 }
}
```

---

Вот что получилось.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>

void update() {
 printf("update complete\n");
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
  int timerfd, delay = 5, s;
  char buf[200];

  struct itimerspec t = {0};
  t.it_value.tv_sec = t.it_interval.tv_sec = delay; // первое срабатывание и интервал через delay сек.

  timerfd=timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,TFD_NONBLOCK);//создаем таймер
  if (timerfd_settime(timerfd,0,&t,0)==-1) err(1, "timerfd_settime");//применяем значение интервала срабатывания

  fd_set fds;
  FD_ZERO (&fds);
  FD_SET (timerfd, &fds);

  struct timeval timeout = {0, 0};

  while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)!=NULL) {
   printf("%s",buf); // на самом деле обрабатываем строку, а пока просто выводим данные
   if (select(timerfd,&fds,NULL,NULL,&timeout)>0) update(); // проверка на истечение таймера
  }
}
```

Но конечно не работает, т.к. не совсем понимаю как нужно вытаскивать информацию о срабатывании через select.

За while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)!=NULL) не цепляйтесь) Это нужно для сторонней программы (можно сказать будет аналог syslog). Не беда если интервал между внесением данных будет больше интервала таймера, т.к. в какой то момент времени данные будут прилетать каждые 2-3 мс, а в другое - несколько минут.

Другими словами - нужно проверить после ввода данных не истек ли таймер. Если истек, то запускаем какой-то апдейт, а после заново бы запустить таймер. Если нет, то продолжаем ждать ввод данных.

---

Получилось желаемое))

```
while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)!=NULL) {
 printf("%s",buf);
 if (read(timerfd,&exp,sizeof(uint64_t))>0) {update();}
}
```

Теперь остался вопрос по поводу перезапуска таймера, если хочется изменить его интервал. А так же корректно ли так смотреть таймер.

---

Конечный вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>

void update() {
 printf("update complete\n");
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
  int timerfd, delay = 5, s;
  char buf[200];
  uint64_t exp;

  struct itimerspec t = {0};
  t.it_value.tv_sec = delay; // первое срабатывание
  t.it_interval.tv_sec = 0; // интервал в 0

  timerfd=timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,TFD_NONBLOCK);//создаем таймер
  if (timerfd_settime(timerfd,0,&t,0)==-1) err(1, "timerfd_settime");//применяем значение интервала срабатывания

  struct timeval timeout = {0,0};

  while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)!=NULL) {
   if (read(timerfd,&exp,sizeof(uint64_t))>0) {
    update();
    t.it_value.tv_sec=delay;
    if (timerfd_settime(timerfd,0,&t,0)==-1) err(1, "timerfd_settime");//применяем значение интервала срабатывания 
   }


   printf("%s",buf); // на самом деле обрабатываем строку, а пока просто выводим данные
  }
}
```

Comment: ОС какая? (в \*nix для однопоточной программы я бы посмотрел на [setitimer](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer), только не забудьте сделать переменную, связывающую код обработчика сигнала с остальным кодом volatile)

Comment: Опять же, многое зависит от реализации `если он что-то ввел`. Если тут используете select/poll/epoll, то логично посмотреть также на [timerfd_create](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timerfd_create).

Comment: Да забыл, ОС - Linux. Поглядим функции.

Comment: Посмотрел в сторону timerfd_create, но по примеру его реализации не заметил применение цикла, чтобы программа выполняла свои действия. Может кто даст пример такой?
Вообще нужно чтобы программа, как описано выше, выполняла функционал. Но когда запускается по времени функция обновления данных, нужно чтобы программа свою операцибю приостановила, т.к. в этой функции я выбрал простой метод обновления - обнуления списка и загрузка его заного.

Comment: Посмотите man-ы на `select/poll` и попишите примеры. Все станет очевидно. Т.е. когда определили активность на fd таймера, читаете 8 байт из него и вызываете свой `update()`. Если хотите сделать дескриптор, возвращаемый `fd = timerfd_create(...)` неблокируемым (боитесь, что пропустили  несколько его срабатываний), то    `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK)` в помощь. (imho в `man timerfd_create` довольно детально все расписано). / Если будут проблемы, сообщите, тогда на днях набросаю какой-нибудь примерчик.

Comment: @avp, набросайте, пожалуйста, примерчик. Я пока разбираюсь, стало немного понятнее, но вдруг не туда сверну.

Comment: Преобразовал в правки то, что выглядело как дополнение к задаче (т.к. завершалось вопросами). Если будут ещё дополнения, то пожалуйста не публикуйте их как ответы, а добавляйте в вопрос, используя кнопку [edit].

Comment: Если я ошибся с переносом — сообщайте, исправлю.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, спасибо, приму к сведению. Переносы правильные.

Comment: @nerik: ладно, хорошо )

Comment: @nerik, посмотрел Ваши (уже удаленные) ответы. Я бы сказал, что всюду одна и та же принципиальная ошибка проектирования. При работе с select/poll (imho poll, вообще-то, удобней, но это не принципиально)  "main-loop" программы должен вращаться вокруг этого select/poll (это некий "коммутатор" событий, на которые реагирует программа) и в этом цикле не должно быть вызовов, потенциально ожидающих чего-либо.

Comment: @avp, я не удалял ответы. Их перенес в тело вопроса Nick Volynkin. Вы правы насчет main-loop, но я пока попробую мой вариант, а далее если будут какие-то проблемы, то перепишу на Ваш вариант. За вчерашний день тестовый образец показался себя хорошо, не хотелось бы его зря трогать) А так спасибо за код.

Comment: @nerik, перечитал обновленный вопрос. Если Вам в самом деле всего-то и нужно `Другими словами - нужно проверить после ввода данных не истек ли таймер...`, то может лучше посмотреть [man timer_create](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html) (и сопутствующие), а можно и просто самому брать текущее время [man 2 time](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) и сравнивать с запланированным временем (это **очень просто**).

Comment: @avp я воспользовался timer_create, а именно в timerfd_settime указываю только старт таймера (интервал в 0), после проверки истечения таймера (через read при TFD_NONBLOCK) я завного использую timerfd_settime (старт через столько то секунд, а интервал опять в 0). Получилось очень сносно)) Сейчас выложу пример в вопросе.

Comment: @nerik, ну, работает и ладно. А `if ((now = time(0)) > tlimit)` чем не понравилось? Слишком тривиально?

Comment: @avp на момент реализации программы, не думал о таком варианте. А сейчас раз работает, чего-то трогать уже не охота. Но если будут проблемы, то воспользуюсь этим вариантом. А так спасибо за содействие)

Answer (score 2):

Ловите. Только тут 5 секунд (минуты мне ждать тоскливо...).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int
update (const char *text, const char *fname)
{
  FILE *f = fopen(fname, "w");

  return f ? (fputs(text, f), !fclose(f)) : 0;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int nfds, delay = 5, modify = 0;
  if (av[1]) 
    if ((delay = atoi(*(++av))) < 1)
      delay = 5;

  char *sfname = av[1] ? av[1] : "save.txt",
    *line = 0, *text = strdup("");
  size_t sz = 0, tsz = 0;

  struct pollfd fds[2] = {
    {0, POLLIN}, 
    {timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, TFD_NONBLOCK), POLLIN}
  };

  if (fds[1].fd < 0)
    err(1, "timerfd_create");
  struct itimerspec t = {0};
  // первое срабатывание и интервал через delay сек.
  t.it_value.tv_sec = t.it_interval.tv_sec = delay; 
  if (timerfd_settime(fds[1].fd, 0, &t, 0) == -1)
    err(1, "timerfd_settime");

  while ((nfds = poll(fds, 2, -1)) > 0) {
    /* сразу в голову что-то не пришло,
       а может простейший способ это таймаут тут (третий аргумент в poll), 
       только его надо все время пересчитывать перед poll,
       зная время последнего выполнения update().
    */
    if (fds[0].revents) {
      int l;
      if ((l = getline(&line, &sz, stdin)) == -1) {
        update(text, sfname);
        return puts("Bye") == EOF;
      }
      text = realloc(text, tsz + l + 1);
      strcpy(text + tsz, line);
      tsz += l;
      modify = 1;
    }
    if (fds[1].revents) {
      //      puts("timer");
      errno = 0;
      long long nt;
      while(read(fds[1].fd, &nt, sizeof(nt)) > 0);
      if (errno != EAGAIN)
        err(1, "timer read %lld", nt);

      if (modify)
        modify = update(text, sfname);
    }
  }
  printf("nfds = %d\n", nfds);

  err(1, "poll");
}
```

Что непонятно, спрашивайте.

**UPDATE**

Самый простой "таймер" с разрешением 1 секунда.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

static int
update (const char *text, const char *fname)
{
  FILE *f = fopen(fname, "w");

  return f ? (fputs(text, f), !fclose(f)) : 0;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int l, delay = 5;
  if (av[1]) 
    if ((delay = atoi(*(++av))) < 1)
      delay = 5;
  time_t now = time(0), tlimit = now + delay;

  char *sfname = av[1] ? av[1] : (char *)"save.txt",
    *line = 0, *text = strdup("");
  size_t sz = 0, tsz = 0;

  while ((l = getline(&line, &sz, stdin)) != -1) {
    text = (char *)realloc(text, tsz + l + 1);
    strcpy(text + tsz, line);
    tsz += l;
    if ((now = time(0)) > tlimit) { // проверяем, истек ли наш "таймер"
      update(text, sfname);
      tlimit = now + delay; // переустанавливаем на желаемый интервал
    }
  }

  update(text, sfname);

  return puts("Bye") == EOF;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, пошел разбирать)

Comment: @nerik, раз уж Вы все равно собираетесь  опрашивать таймер после ожидания какого-то ввода, то в **update** самый простой вариант (не требующий на самом деле никаких таймеров).